# Ion Item white space on left side

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to make ion list items full width as the screen but here is the output.

[image]

Following in the CSS file code of the class:

```
.divider{
    background: #D2CECE;
    font-size: 1em;
    min-height: 1em !important;
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow: visible !important;
    border-top: 1px solid #050404 !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #050404 !important;
}
```

There is a white space on the left side. How do I make it full width?

Comment: Have you already tried by adding the `no-padding` and `no-margin` attributes to the `ion-list` or the `ion-item`?

Comment: Yes. That does not work.

Comment: try setting `no-padding` to ion-content

Comment: No. Still the same. You see the right side is ok. It's overflowing. Not sure what's wrong with left. I want to make it full screen width. Is there a different solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ionic property like

```
 <ion-item lines="full"></ion-item>
```

Which is works for both IONIC 3 & IONIC 4